# geom_bar plots 0 values with height, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am making a bar graph with ggplot2. However, I have a couple of items which have a value of 0. These are plotted with height, though, as in the image below. Does anyone know how to make it so that the values of 0 have no height? I've looked around for an answer to this but haven't been able to come across the right keywords that lead to an explanation for this behavior. I've included a reproducible example.

**Example plot:**

[image: Actual output]

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Never", 
"Sometimes", "Often", "Always"), class = "factor"), Freq = c("2", 
"4", "0", "0")), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

**Edit:** As per Gregor's comment, this is because df$Freq is a factor. It is fixed with:

```
df$Freq <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Freq))
```

Comment: Your `Freq` column is a factor. Use `df$Freq = as.numeric(as.character(df$Freq))` to convert it to numeric.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!